# Proof/Disproof order preserving isomorphism between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**How i suppose prove these excercises formally , i must to fins preserved - isomorphism between each 2 sets ? , I'll be thankful for some help**

Proof/Disproof:

$1.$ $A=([0,1],\leq) \cong ([0,\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{1}{2},1],\leq)=B$ with the regular order on $\mathbb R$.

**My solution:**

$1.$ I am really not sure but i think its true becuase just
one point ($\frac{1}{2}$) is missing.
A has min and max points and there are no successor and
predecessor- and So B.

I dont know how to formal this proof.

Comment: Asking a lot of questions in one is not recommended on MSE (see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For the first part of your problem, $A$ and $B$ are not order-isomorphic: $A$ is complete: every increasing sequence has a least-upper bound. $B$ is not complete. For the rest, I suggest you ask separate questions.

Comment: I will ask seperate questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $<_i$ is a linear order on $C_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and that $f:C_1\to C_2$ is an order-isomorphism. That is, $f$ is a bijection and $\forall d,e\in C_1\,(d<_1 e\implies f(d)<_2 f(e)\,)$.

If $S\subseteq C_1$ and if $a=lub_1S$ exists then $f(a)=lub_2 f[S].$

( Where $f[S]=\{f(x):x\in S\}$.)

Proof: (i.) $f(a)$ is a $<_2$-upper-bound for $f[S]$ because $s\in S\implies s\le_1 a\implies f(s)\le_2 f(a).$

(ii.) For any $t\in C_2$ we have

$t<_2 f(a)\implies f^{-1}(t)<_1 a=lub_1 S\implies$

$(f^{-1}(t)$ is not a $<_1$-upper bound for $S)\implies$

$\exists s\in S\,(f^{-1}(t)<_1 s)\implies$ $\exists s\in S\,(t<_2 f(s)\implies$

$(t$ is not a $<_2$-upper-bound for $f[S]\,).$

For your Q, observe that every $S\subseteq A$ has a lub in $A$, but $[0,1/2)$ has $no$ lub in  $B$. If $f:A\to B$ were an order-isomorphism we would have $f(lub_A(f^{-1}[0,1/2)\,)=lub_B f[f^{-1}[0,1/2)]
=lub_B[0,1/2).$

Comment: Whether you prefer to $define$ your linear orders in terms of $<$ or $\le$ is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to do this is to use the connectedness property of $[0, 1]$.

Consider the following statement $\Phi(P, \leq)$ about a partial order $(P, \leq)$, where $a < b$ is an abbreviation of $a \leq b \land a \neq b$:

> There exist subsets $Q, R \subseteq P$ such that (1) $Q \cup R = P$, (2) $\forall x \in Q \forall y \in R (x < y)$, (3) $\forall x \in Q \exists y \in Q (x < y)$, and (4) $\forall x \in R \exists y \in R (y < x)$, (5) $\exists x (x \in Q)$, and (6) $\exists x (x \in R)$

Exercise: show if two partial orders $(P_1, \leq_1)$ and $(P_2, \leq_2)$ are isomorphic, then $\Phi(P_1, \leq_1) \to \Phi(P_2, \leq_2)$.

Clearly $\Phi([0, 1/2) \cup (1/2, 1], \leq)$ holds. Simply take $Q = [0, 1/2)$ and $R = (1/2, 1]$.

If the two orders were isomorphic, then $\Phi([0, 1], \leq)$ would also hold.

But this statement does not hold. For suppose it did hold for subsets $Q, R$. Then $Q$ and $R$ would both be open, inhabited sets which covered $[0, 1]$ but did not overlap. This contradicts the fact that $[0, 1]$ is connected.